# Add to wishlist button on Category Page Opencart:2.3.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I want to add a wishlist icon on Category page, like on the Product page.

```
<a onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><i class="icon-heart"></i> </a>
```

But this did not work in Category page. I also checked for jquery in product page with keyword "wishlist", but didn't find at all.
So, where does this even is handled? And how can I implement it on Category Page?

Comment: While on a category page if you type in `wishlist.add(56);` in the browser console end hit `return` do you get an error message?

Comment: Yes, Solved. When i change '$product_id;' to '$product['product_id'];', then it has an ID(Like: wishlist.add(56)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Solved.

When I change

```
$product_id;
```

to

`$product['product_id'];`

Then it has an ID(Like: `wishlist.add(56)`).